# PHP accessing a property via variable which results in PHP8.2 deprecation notice, how to handle?

Tags: php

Consider the following, a utility class that sets an objects property via a variable.

```
<?php
class Foo {

    protected $var = null;
    
    public function addValue($someVar, $someValue)
    {
            $this->$someVar = $someValue;
    }
}
```

So, calling `addValue` works, but in PHP8.2 it outputs a deprecation notice.

```
Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property Foo::$userInput is deprecated in ... on line ....
```

So in order to fix this you add the property to then class, right? Well, my project emits hundreds of these calls, what am I to do - add all possibilities to the class?

Help!

Comment: Yep, that's what I want. Just to note, adding "#[AllowDynamicProperties]" before my class declaration was what I needed.